# How to declare a integer outside of a function

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, http, flask

I am trying to add data to my mysql database with a HTTP post request, but in the way it's set up now, if we post more than once, the data from the first post gets changed to 0 because I declare all the variables in the same definition. How can I fix this?

I have tried to declare a global variable in a second def, but it just loops that def instead of the one I have now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pymysql.cursors
from flask import Flask, request
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

connection = pymysql.connect('localhost','esp', 'password', 'points')
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/post', methods = ["POST"])


def post():

    hits1 = 0
    hits2 = 0
    punch1 = 0
    punch2 = 0
    kick1 = 0
    kick2 = 0
    takedown1 = 0
    takedown2 = 0

    print(request.data)
    cipher = AES.new("abcdefghijklmnop")

    decryptedData = cipher.decrypt(request.data)


    data = decryptedData.decode("utf-8")
    print(data)

    print(data)
    if(data[:1]=="e"):
        if(data[1:2] == "1"):
            hits1+=1
            print(hits1)

    if (data[:1]=="1"):
        if(data[1:2]=="1"):
            punch1+=1
        elif(data[1:2]=="2"):
            kick1+=1
        elif(data[1:2]=="3"):
            takedown1+=1
    elif(data[:1]=="2"):
        if(data[1:2]=="1"):
            punch2+=1
        elif(data[1:2]=="2"):
            kick2+=1
        elif(data[1:2]=="3"):
            takedown2+=1
    points1 = punch1 + kick1 * 2 + takedown1 * 3
    points2 = punch2 + kick2 * 2 + takedown2 * 3
    print(points1)
    print(points2)

    try:
       with connection.cursor() as cursor:


            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO points values({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})".format(1, hits1, kick1, punch1, takedown1, points1))
            cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO points values({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})".format(2, hits2, kick2, punch2, takedown2, points2))


            connection.commit()
            print ("Data committed")
            return 'ok'
    except:
       connection.close()
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 8090)
```

The value of the previous post gets changed to 0, but i want to keep that value

Comment: It is not clear to me what value you want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to keep the variables you define at the top of your function (`hits1`, `hits2`...). The problem, as you stated, is that these variables are redefined every time your function is called.

The simplest way to do that (though a questionable design) is to use global variables. To define a global variable, you could do this:

```py
hits1 = 0
hits2 = 0
# ...

@app.route('/post', methods = ["POST"])
def post():
    global hits1, hits2

    # ...
```

That way, the values will be kept between requests. A way that I (personnally) prefer, though it's still the same idea, is to keep your data in a "Storage" class:

```py
class Storage:
    hits1 = 0
    hits2 = 0
    # ...

@app.route('/post', methods = ["POST"])
def post():
    # Instead of just using hits1, hits2, ...
    # We now use Storage.hits1, ...
    # Example:

    # ...

    Storage.points1 = Storage.punch1 + Storage.kick1 * 2 + Storage.takedown1 * 3

    # ...
```

That works. But of course, this is forgotten every time you restart your Flask application. If you want actual persistence (which is what you're trying to achieve, as you're using a database), is something that would query the database (potentially with a cache in order to limit the number of queries) every time a user makes a request to your server:

```py
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        # Connect to your database
        self._hits1 = None

    @property
    def hits1(self):
        if self._hits1 is None:
            # self._hits1 = (Load data from the database)

        return self._hits1

    # ...

database = Database()

@app.route('/post', methods = ["POST"])
def post():
    # Loads from the database
    hits1 = database.hits1

    # ...

    # In this case, you'd probably want to move your INSERT query to your database class
```

A few comments: if you want to keep your values between requests, it's *probably* that you want to `UPDATE` your database instead of `INSERT`ing data (but that's just my interpretation of your code).

Also, using `an_sql_request.format(data)` is a very bad practice, as it can help potential SQL injections. Most database drivers offer a way of preparing queries. For example with `mysql.connector`:

```py
cur = connection.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cur.execute(sql, (value_for_col1, value_for_col2))
```